# Does truncating anchor text hurt SEO?

Tags: seo

Does truncating the anchor text in a link affect SEO negatively? Google is only seeing part of the relevant text in the anchor. I have a long list of product urls that I need to link to from my homepage. Vast majority of those links are under 30 characters but some are really long, over 100 characters. For UI/UX reasons I have been given a character cap on these anchors so I have to find the best solution for the anchor text I use given that restriction. I'm very interested in the SEO perspective people can give.

Example Anchor Text:
NormalPartNameNumberTruncated

VeryVeryLongWhichIsPartNumberTruncated...

AnotherVeryVeryLongPartNumberWhichIsTruncated...

NeedToLimitMyVeryLongPartNumberAnchors...

Questions:

Should I use ellipsis at the end of truncated anchors text or leave as many chars as possible?
Does Google look negatively at truncating really long anchors?

Thanks in advance for thoughts and insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only affect truncating will have is any text removed from the anchor text won't be considered when Google determines the value of that link for the receiving page. So if these are internal links you will be reducing the value of those links. But if the text is really long otherwise, it's a tomato/tomato scenario as you can be sure Google limits the amount of keywords it considers in links as spammers are sure to cram spammy links full of text.

Bottom line, if the text you are truncating is very long, this won't hurt you. If it helps your users, then it is worth doing.

Answer (score 1):

How about leaving the entire text there and using `text-overflow: ellipsis`?  See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html

(That's subject to figuring out whether old browsers that don't support `text-overflow: ellipsis` are important to you, and whether there's a workaround.)

Comment: Keep in mind that `text-overflow: ellipsis` alone is a solution for one-liner texts only